# Access denied error when building solution in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I get the following error in Visual Studio 2005 when doing a build:

> Error 9   Cannot register assembly
>   "E:\CSharp\project\Some.Assembly.dll"
>   - access denied. Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED)) project

It happens only intermittantly and does go away if I restart the IDE, however this is incredibly annoying and I would like to put a stop to it happening permanently, if I can. I've checked the assembly itself, and it is not set to read only, so I've no idea why Visul Studio is getting a lock on it. I am working in Debug mode.

I've had a look around google, but can't seem to find anything other than "restart VS". Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can resolve this annoying problem?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you have a DLL that gets locked every now and then, preventing VS from overwriting/locking it. Have you tried using tools like Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), or Unlocker (http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to see what is locking the DLL? Unlocker in particular has saved me many a time.

As noted in the comments below (Thanks [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)), you can also kill an individual lock from within Process Explorer.

Comment: Just installed Unlocker, and it says it didn't find a locking handle. Process Explorer says devenv.exe has the dll open in Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\ProjectAssemblies\jl-s2cov01\Some.Assembly.dll, so it could be that.

Comment: Try deleting the dll, and let Unlocker figure it out (you don't have to physically delete it, unless it will be rebuilt anyway). It gives you the option to do nothing.

Comment: note that you can also kill individual locks from within Process Explorer -- have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by Visual Studio requiring administrator rights on Windows 7 or higher. To check, see whether the registry key mentioned below is set. If not, copy into a `.reg` and merge. Be sure to check that your Visual Studio 2005 installation path in the `.reg` file is correct!

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Run Visual Studio 2005 with administrator rights
; This is required to run / debug the program directly from the IDE
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe"="~ RUNASADMIN"
```