# ErrorThe type or namespace name 'AxWMPLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, windows-media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

What is the possible reference for the handler `AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler` ?

When I pass this event in the method,

```
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender,AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
```

Compiling throws the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'AxWMPLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Visual Studio then make sure you have `AxWMPLib` listed under References in Solution Explorer. If you have an embedded Windows Media Player control in a form, it should have been added automatically along with `WMPLib`.

An easy way to add these libraries if they are missing is to add a Windows Media Player control to a form (an existing one will do). Right-click on the Toolbox and pick "Choose Items..." from the context menu, then tick the "Windows Media Player" control on the "COM components" tab and click OK. You should now have a little Windows Media Player icon attached to your cursor; click on the form to add it. This will add the AxWMPLib and WMPLib references to your solution. You can then delete the Windows Media Player control you just added if you don't need it.

Comment: What if I don't see the "Windows Media Player" in the "COM components ? I have windows 10 and visual studio 2019 community edition.

Comment: If you don't have the "Windows Media Player" option in the "COM components" list means that your windows installation doesn't include "Windows media player". To enable this windows feature, open up windows menu and search for "Turn Windows features on or off. Expand the "Media features" and enable the "Windows Media Player" option. Give it a couple of minutes to get installed and then you are ready to see it under to COM menu as refered by @Alistair

Comment: When I add Media Player from the List of COM components in VS 2019/Win 10 it appears in the Toolbox but with no icon. If I try and drag this icon onto a designer window I get the error 'failed to create component AxHost'.

Answer (score 0):

See [Access denied error when building solution in Visual Studio 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81071/access-denied-error-when-building-solution-in-visual-studio-2005)

This may be caused by Visual Studio requiring administrator rights on Windows 7 or higher.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question...